solution-verification | Find the minimum of the expression $E(x)= \frac{-2x^4+8x^3-8x^2-9}{x^4-4x^3+4x^2+3}$
the problem
a) Show that, for any real number $x$, $x^4-4x^3+4x^2+3>0$
b) Find the minimum of the expression $E(x)= \frac{-2x^4+8x^3-8x^2-9}{x^4-4x^3+4x^2+3}$, where x is a number real
my idea
So for point a) we know that $x^4-4x^3+4x^2+3= x^2(x^2-4x+4)+3= x^2(x-2)^2+3 \geq 3 > 0$
Im not really sure on point b.
$E(x)= \frac{-2x^4+8x^3-8x^2-9}{x^4-4x^3+4x^2+3}=-2-\frac{3}{x^4-4x^3+4x^2+3}$
Im not sure on this part where I prelucated some info to get to the wanted expression: above I demonstrated that $x^4-4x^3+4x^2+3 \geq 3$ which means that $\frac{3}{x^4-4x^3+4x^2+3} \leq 1=> -\frac{3}{x^4-4x^3+4x^2+3} \geq -1=> -2-\frac{3}{x^4-4x^3+4x^2+3} \geq -3$
So the minimum of the expression is -3.
Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

$$
E(x)= \frac{-2x^4+8x^3-8x^2-9}{x^4-4x^3+4x^2+3}=-\frac{2x^2(x-2)^2+9}{x^2(x-2)^2+3}=-\left(2+\frac3{x^2(x-2)^2+3}\right)
$$
$$
x^2(x-2)^2+3\ge3 \implies \frac1{x^2(x-2)^2+3}\le \frac13\implies-\frac3{x^2(x-2)^2+3}\ge -1
$$
So the minimum is $-2-1=-3
$

Thank you so much for your answer! So, my idea is right, isn't it?

yep its correct
